# Apps Script - row of clicked button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm converting an Excel document to Google Spreadsheet. In my document I have a column with buttons and each button executes the VBA function with the data from it's own row. Each button use the same function and inside that function I simply check the row of clicked button by:

```
Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
r = b.TopLeftCell.Row
```

How can I check the row of clicked image (with assigned script) in Apps Script?

Comment: I wouldn't use image buttons.  If the functions are likely to finish is less than 30 seconds you could use checkboxes in a column and onEdit trigger by distinguishing the function by `e.range.rowStart`.  I would probably use a sidebar and build a table with buttons in it in HTML

Comment: Another approach would be to put your cursor on the row that you want and let the  single function figure out what row you're on.  Then you only need one button or menu item.

Comment: Welcome. Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This should help you to get a start on the dialog or sidebar approach.

```
function buttonColumn() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var html='<table>';
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td><input type="button" value="%s" onClick="function' + Number(i+1) + '(' + Number(i+1) + ');" /></td></tr>',"Button For Row "  + Number(i+1));
  })
  html+='</table>';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

This creates a button for each row except the header row with the onClick attribute filled in.

[image]

And here's what the button sidebar looks like:

[image]

[UI Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html)

One of the nice things about this approach is that the buttons get added automatically when you add rows.

Comment: Thank you for this approach, however I can't use this method as it's too different from the original Excel spreadsheet UI and sidebar takes a lot of working space. I will look at checkboxes with onEdit though, as it's the closest thing to what I'm searching for.